# Base layer in OpenLayers 2/3

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers, basemap

I know in OpenLayers 2 there is the concept of "base layer", which can be set by `map.setBaseLayer(layer)`. But I am not sure which effect this has and if there is an equivalent in OpenLayers 3.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you asking layer selector option which has baselayers and overlays?

Comment: What I mean is:
When I set a base layer in ol2, the map gets (so I think) some properties from the base layer, e.g. projection and zoom levels. (Please correct me if I am wrong)

Do I have the same behaviour in ol3?

Comment: Yes everything is same, just the JavaScript library has changed. Things depend on WMS version. You can see a working example of ol3 with baselayer and overlays from here. http://geospatialearth.in/ol3/main/

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply. That means if in ol3 I set the baseLayer, the map inherits e.g. the projection from the baselayer?